# change product-grid class to row class in Boilerplate - Bootstrap

Tags: magento-1.9

Assuming that I'm new to Magento and I would like to create a Magento theme changing the current product-grid classes etc to the Bootstrap structure and I'm using the Boilerplate theme. I would like to change the product-grid list with a row class, but I can't understand in which file I have to do this and if it's a good practice or not.

Isn't the right path `app\design\frontend\boilerplate\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`?

I've tried to change this file changing the class name, but nothing happens.

What should I do?

Here is the screenshot of the webpage:

[image: frontend screenshot]

Comment: Is your boilerplate theme active? In `System > configuration > design`? Also copying across the template file to your custom theme is the right thing to do. A good resource is http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentoenterprise/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf learning about the theme hierarchy

Comment: Yes, it's active...when i've installed the theme, I don't know, but I think i've copied the files in the right directories. Thanks for the resource, i'll check it tomorrow, anyway, is it possible that i can see the grid even if i don't have a list.phtml in my list?

Comment: Where did you add the class? In the `list.phtml` there are two grid type `list` and `grid` just make sure you add the class to both of these `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Comment: Done...but that isn't working for some reason i don't understand. Any change doesn't affect the page.

Comment: are you able to post a screenshot of the file and the config page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn On template hints to see which template is actually used 
[image: Final Outcome]

How to turn on Template Path Hints?

1. Open the admin control panel
2. Open the system tab and select configuration
3. Select Main Website or Name of your website (NOT DEFAULT CONFIG) from the Current Configuration Scope drop down
4. Select Developer on the left sidebar
5. Open the Debug drop down
6. Set Template Path Hints To Yes
7. Click on Save Config to save down your changes

**Remember to clear cache after you make changes**

**To clear the cache**, simply delete everything from the /var/cache directory and then reload your website in your browser. To clear all sessions, you can also delete everything from the /var/session folder within your Magento installation directory.

Comment: I've enabled it already yesterday, but the list is the only part that doesn't show me any red rect

Comment: add the screenshot to the answer and pointt what are you trying to chnage

Comment: Solved: the path was app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\widget\new\content\new_grid.phtml